# How to find the smallest circle for two tangent points

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am trying to write a program to draw arcs with directions defined as tangent going between two positions.

I have two vector positions for an arc **A** and **B** which defines a start position (**A**) and end position (**B**). Each one also has a tangent which defines the direction of travel on the arc.

I am looking to find the smallest possible arc that fits the tangents so i can get the radius, origin and start/end angles (within range of -360 and 360 degrees).

Here is a visual example:
[image]

So the information i have is:

1. Start point **A** (vector)
2. Start direction which is tangent (unit vector)
3. End point **B** (vector)
4. End direction which is tangent (unit vector)

Looking to find:

1. Radius
2. Origin
3. Start Angle where $\theta$ is in range of [-360,360]
4. End Angle where $\phi$ is in range of [-360,360]

Is it possible to find the arcs from just this information alone?

Thanks

Comment: well if you know the tangent points and directions you can find the center and radius hence determine the circle.

Comment: Radii of a circle are perpendicular to a tangent. I would find the intersection of the normal lines in the coordinate plane unless this is harder than it seems. And it looks like it is, because the intersection of the normals has to be equidistant from the starting points. Is that an established precondition?

Comment: Is there always guaranteed to exist a circle for any position of the two points and any direction of the two tangents ?
Though the part that i am more stumped on is the arc direction aspect since there are two arc solutions...

Comment: @WDUK No. Imagine two vectors pointing in opposite directions and the normal lines not intersecting. For all other cases, normal lines must intersect, and a circle can be drawn. And... I just updated my previous comment because there's a also a requirement that the intersection of the normals are equidistant from the start and end points. Otherwise, it wouldn't be a circle! Past that, it looks like an easy problem. So... is it an established precondition?

Comment: If you know the vectors A&B, couldn't you then find angle difference between them as a resultant so you can tell the program how much of a 'circle' you want and then you can take that as a fraction of the circumference etc.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley its not established, but i can rule out pointing in opposite directions in my code by checking the dot product so for all intents and purposes there would be a solution.

Comment: @JosephHulme i can find the angle between but thats always the acute angle - its still a bit confusing how to correctly find the start and end angles based on any quadrant combinations

Comment: How do you know that the two points and tangent directions lie on a circular arc in the first place? If you just pick two random points and direction vectors, they pretty much never do. When they do lie on a circular arc and the directions of the tangents aren’t contradictory, unless they’re endpoints of a diameter the arc is unique.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3521689/265466. The answer doesn’t actually provide a solution in the case that a circular arc is possible, though.

Comment: @amd assume there is a solution though, how do you define the arc involving the direction ?

Comment: As In [sammy gerbil’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3637438/265466): drop a a perpendicular from each point and intersect them to find the arc’s center. In homogeneous coordinates, that’s a couple of dot product, a cross product and a scalar multiplication. You can determine the direction in which the arc is traced by examining the sign of the determinant of either of the tangent vectors and the radial vector to that point (or just rotate the radial vector 90° in a known direction and compare signs with the tangent vector).

Comment: Hmm i see, seems i need to study more math first lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer provides excellent detail on the underlying structure of the problem. Based on the comments in response to the question, here's framework to get to an actual answer. Get a piece of paper and a pencil out to draw with me.

Given a point $A=(x_a,y_a)$ and a tangent $A'=(x'_a,y'_a)$, and another point $B=(x_b,y_b)$ (assuming B' works as well), we can plop this all in the coordinate plane. The normal passing through A would be $y-y_a = -\frac{x'_a}{y'_a}(x-x_a)$. Call that $N$. Now we need a line from $B$ intersecting $N$ at point $C$ such that $\overline{AC}=\overline{BC}$. Borrowing again from Sammy's answer, we can get the perpendicular bisector of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ and find where it intersects $N$. So... we find the midpoint of A and B, and the normal is again, simply the negative inverse of the slope:
$y-\frac{y_a+y_b}2=-\frac{x_b-x_a}{y_b-y_a}(x-\frac{x_a+x_b}2)$. Call this $P$.

The intersection of $N$ and $P$ is a system of equations with a few too many variables for me to work through right now (it's 11:30 PM), but it get's you a point. It is the coveted intersection, $C$.

> This point is equidistant from $A$ and $B$ by the SAS congruence theorem, if you were wondering. If you draw out $A, A', N, AB,$ and $B$, you'll see $\overline{BC}$ and a few triangles to prove it.

This, at long last, is the center of the circle. The distances AC or BC can serve as the radius. They are equal (see spoiler above).

Now, there are some caveats. This is assuming everything falls into place, as in, the tangent to B allows for an arc to form. Which is what I discuss below.
I program here and there too (Python and Java), so what I would do is have a user defined $A, A',$ and $B$. Unless B lies on A', I'm pretty sure there is always a solution. Any questions, please comment! This is a fun little project I might venture on now...

Comment: Whats $y-y_a$ ? Did you mean $y'_a - y_a$  not sure what $y$ represents ? Same for $x$ ?

Comment: I'm using point-slope form. $y$ by itself is a function of $x$. $y$ sub anything is a point, and prime marks a tangent (in line with calculus notation)

Comment: Hmm i see, not particularly familiar with calculus at least in terms of translating it into code so the syntax is bit tricky to understand.

Answer (score 1):

3 points on the circumference are sufficient to define a circle. Defining a tangent line is equivalent to defining another 1 point, since 2 points infinitesimally close together define a tangent line.

Given **two points** A, B on the circumference, the line AB is a **chord**. The centre of the circle lies on the perpendicular bisector of AB. The smallest possible circle will have AB as diameter  - ie the centre of the circle will be at the midpoint of AB. A circle of any diameter larger than this can be drawn.

If you also specify **one tangent line**, say that at A, then you define the circle uniquely. Effectively you have provided a 3rd point. The centre lies on the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of AB and the normal to the tangent at A.

If you further specify **a second tangent line** at B, in addition to points A 
 and B and the tangent at A, then you have provided too much information. You have effectively provided a 4th point on the circumference. You have **over-constrained** the problem. In general there will be no way of drawing a circle - unless the tangent at B fits the circle already determined by points A, B and the tangent at A.

Comment: For two tangents and two points, what requirements are needed for there to be a solution ?

Comment: The tangents must intersect on the perpendicular bisector of line AB.

Comment: The two direction vectors also have to be compatible with traversing the arc in a particular direction. If you reverse either the $A$ or the $B$ vectors in the OP’s diagram, there’s also no solution.